# Variável PHP com texto de um select(combobox)

Tags: php, javascript, html

Como colocar em uma variável php o texto e não o value de um option? Se for java script, mesmo assim como coloco o texto na variável, pois preciso trabalhar com esse texto.

exemplo html:

```html
<select name="uf" id="uf">
 <option value="1">AC</option>
 <option value="2">AL</option>
 <option value="3">AM</option>
  </select>
```

depois do submit só consigo pegar o valor:

```
$idestado = $_POST['UF'];
```

como coloco o texto nessa variável:

```
$nomeestado = ???
```

Comment: De onde vem esse HTML? Porque tens numeros no value e não o mesmo que o `.innerHTML`? se não precisares do value no JavaScript o melhor era ter o mesmo nos dois... ou tirar o value.

Comment: Eu uso números no value pois faço um select de cidades por id do estado.

Comment: Ok, ou usas AJAX ou sugiro que mudes o que tens no value para dar para usar no JS e servidor. Senão o submit da form só envia o value...

Comment: ok, então como faço no AJAX?

Comment: @ÁlyssonAlexandre você está usando js para pegar as cidades correto?

Comment: ------------sim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode manter a associação em um array, usá-lo para alimentar o select, e também para obter seu valor depois.

```
<select name="uf">
  <?php

  $estados = array(
    "SP" => "São Paulo",
    "RJ" => "Rio de Janeiro",
  );

  foreach($estados as $k => $v) {
    print('<option value="'.$k.'">'.$v.'</option>'."\n");
  }

  ?>
</select>
```

depois do submit:

```
$uf = $_POST['uf'];
$estado = $estados[$uf];
```

Comment: Obrigado. Deu certo.